# Fix the size of a table even though "display none or block" in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML code:

```
<form:form method="get" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/get_info">
    <table id="tabmenu">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="radio" name="choice" id="np" onClick="Affichenp();"/>Nomet Prenom</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="choice"id="ns" onClick="Afficheppr();"/>Numérode somme</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="choice" id="cn" onClick="Affichecin();"/>CIN</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="nom" id="nom" class="round default-width-input" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="ppr" id="ppr" class="round default-width-input" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="cin" id="cin" class="round default-width-input" /></td>
            <td><input class="button round blue image-right ic-right-arrow" type="submit" value=""></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

This is the code of the functions called by javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function Affichenp() {
    document.getElementById("nom").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("ppr").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("cin").style.display = "none";
}

function Afficheppr() {
    document.getElementById("nom").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("ppr").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("cin").style.display = "none";
}

function Affichecin() {
    document.getElementById("nom").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("ppr").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("cin").style.display = "block";
}
```

When i click on a radio box, I want the input under it to display so when I click on the radio button the number of lines of the table changes. In other words, when I open my page on the first time, I have no input appear so I choose a radio button to give me an input to fill it... So the width of my `td` changes. Any solution?

Comment: What is `form:form` supposed to mean? Do you have some definition for a `form` namespace?

Comment: I use Spring tag. supposed here i have form simple. that is not a problem.

Comment: As you say, I don't think it's immediately clear what you're asking.  Do you want to make a particular `td` or other element have a particular width regardless of whether or not it has content?  In that case why not just assign it a `width` in CSS?

Comment: i tried the width of CSS but not working. now i have 3 choices and i don't want all input fileds appears all at once so i put radio button and to manage my html elements i use a table but the problem is that when the inputs are disapear, my table has a size and when they are showen it has another size ?

Comment: What happened when you used CSS to give the `<td>` elements a defined `width`?

Comment: nothing ! because when i click on a radio button to display the input the width is not any more applied. this is a demo of what i want but there is a difference is that me i have all radio buttons in the first line and the inputs at the second : http://css-tricks.com/examples/ChoiceValuePair/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write that your problem is that the width of your `<td>` changes once an `<input>` is added.  My suggestion would be to give your `<td>` a default width using CSS that's larger than the width of the `<input>` (`200px` is just an example, you can change it as appropriate):

```
#tabmenu td {width:200px;}
```

Also, you can simplify your functions into one by making the `id` an argument:

```
function Affiche(id) {
    document.getElementById("nom").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("ppr").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("cin").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to use `style.visibility = "hidden"` and `style.visibility = "visible"` instead!